# transitive reduction algorithm: pseudocode?

Tags: algorithm, graph, pseudocode

I have been looking for an algorithm to perform a transitive reduction on a graph, but without success. There's nothing in my algorithms bible (Introduction To Algorithms by Cormen et al) and whilst I've seen plenty of transitive closure pseudocode, I haven't been able to track down anything for a reduction. The closest I've got is that there is one in "Algorithmische Graphentheorie" by Volker Turau (ISBN:978-3-486-59057-9), but unfortunately I don't have access to this book! Wikipedia is unhelpful and Google is yet to turn up anything. :^(

Does anyone know of an algorithm for performing a transitive reduction?

Answer (score 21):

See Harry Hsu. "An algorithm for finding a minimal equivalent graph of a digraph.", Journal of the ACM, 22(1):11-16, January 1975.  The simple cubic algorithm below (using an N x N path matrix) suffices for DAGs, but Hsu generalizes it to cyclic graphs.

```
// reflexive reduction
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  m[i][i] = false;

// transitive reduction
for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    if (m[i][j])
      for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k)
        if (m[j][k])
          m[i][k] = false;
```

Comment: (for DAGs) In other words: look at each edge (i,j), remove it if there is a reason for not being in the transitive reduction.  The edges not removed must be inside the transitive reduction.

Comment: According to the reference you cite, you should be starting from the path matrix, not the adjacency matrix

Comment: This does not work for all cases. In a graph with edges (A,B), (B,C), (C,D) and (A,D) the last edge (A,D) should be deleted. It is not, because there is no combination of two edges (m[i][j] and m[j][k]) that leads from A to D.

Comment: @MichaelClerx quite right, I meant path matrix.  Thanks for pointing out the error.

If you have an adjacency matrix, apply Warshal's algorithm first to transitively close it.

Answer (score 8):

The basic gist of the transitive reduction algorithm I used is

```
foreach x in graph.vertices
   foreach y in graph.vertices
      foreach z in graph.vertices
         delete edge xz if edges xy and yz exist
```

The transitive closure algorithm I used in the same script is very similar but the last line is

```
         add edge xz if edges xy and yz OR edge xz exist
```

Comment: You need to add `if (x,z) != (x,y) && (x,z) != (y,z)` before `delete edge...` to avoid incorrect deletions in the event of cycles.  Other than that, and although it'd be better to have a faster linear-time algorithm, I like this answer:  nice and simple.

Comment: Also, if the graph has cycles, this algorithm won't always produce the *minimal* transitive reduction.  For instance, try it on `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` where A points to B for all A and B (even when they're the same).  It should produce something like 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 0, but running this algorithm (with my tweak) brings in 5 -> 2 and 5 -> 4 in addition to 0 -> ... -> 5 -> 0.  Running it without my tweak produces no edges at all.

Comment: I should have stated that my code included checks for the identical edges you mentioned, and also that I'm working solely with DAGs, so the cycles aren't an issue.

Comment: Are you sure of your algorithm for the transitive closure? For that task I would use Floyd-Warshall's algorithm, which is `foreach y in graph.vertices: foreach x in graph.vertices: foreach z in graph.vertices: add edge xz if edges xy and yz exist OR edge xz exist`.  Note the different order in `x` and `y`.  I thought the order mattered.  It doesn't?

Comment: As noted by cmn, thi algorithm does clear edges that connect nodes that are also connected through a path that has more than two edges. Example: A -> B -> C -> D; A -> C; A-> D. The algorithm would clear A -> C, but not A -> D.

Comment: I implemented the transitive reduction algorithm here incl. the additional `if` condition by @JoeyAdams, but sometimes it produces incorrect (not just suboptimal) results. I have a case of a DAG (no cycles!) getting mutilated: V2→V1, V3→V1, V4→V1, V5→V1, V6→V1, V2→V3, V2→V4, V2→V5, V6→V2, V3→V4, V3→V5, V6→V3, V4→V5, V6→V4, V6→V5 gets reduced to V5→V1, V6→V1, V2→V3, V6→V2, V3→V4, V4→V5, V6→V4 while the correct result should be V5→V1, V2→V3, V6→V2, V3→V4, V4→V5. So what is wrong with this algorithm and where can I find a correct one working both cyclic and acyclic directed graphs?

Answer (score 6):

Based on the reference provided by Alan Donovan, which says you should use the path matrix (which has a 1 if there is a path from node i to node j) instead of the adjacency matrix (which has a 1 only if there is an edge from node i to node j).

Some sample python code follows below to show the differences between the solutions

```
def prima(m, title=None):
    """ Prints a matrix to the terminal """
    if title:
        print title
    for row in m:
        print ', '.join([str(x) for x in row])
    print ''

def path(m):
    """ Returns a path matrix """
    p = [list(row) for row in m]
    n = len(p)
    for i in xrange(0, n):
        for j in xrange(0, n):
            if i == j:
                continue
            if p[j][i]:
                for k in xrange(0, n):
                    if p[j][k] == 0:
                        p[j][k] = p[i][k]
    return p

def hsu(m):
    """ Transforms a given directed acyclic graph into its minimal equivalent """
    n = len(m)
    for j in xrange(n):
        for i in xrange(n):
            if m[i][j]:
                for k in xrange(n):
                    if m[j][k]:
                        m[i][k] = 0

m = [   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

prima(m, 'Original matrix')
hsu(m)
prima(m, 'After Hsu')

p = path(m)
prima(p, 'Path matrix')
hsu(p)
prima(p, 'After Hsu')
```

Output:

```
Adjacency matrix
0, 1, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 1
0, 1, 0, 0, 0

After Hsu
0, 1, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 1
0, 1, 0, 0, 0

Path matrix
0, 1, 1, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 0, 1, 1
0, 1, 0, 0, 1
0, 1, 0, 0, 0

After Hsu
0, 0, 1, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 1
0, 1, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: I'm puzzled because it seems that, if you removed the edges in the right order, you could get right back to the original (redundant) adjacency matrix by applying the algorithm to the path matrix. So basically you've gotten nowhere. See this example: http://i.imgur.com/fbt6oK1.png Say you start with just the black edges, and of course you want to eliminate the dotted black/green edge. So you add the red edges to get the path matrix. Then you remove the red edges because they can both be removed by the algorithm. And now you're stuck.

Comment: Using m = [[0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]] as input works fine :)

Comment: I think that It can work as long as you're not unlucky about which edges are removed first.

Comment: Try it, the order makes no difference.

Comment: OK, sorry, you're right, I can't find any case where the dotted black/green edge is removed before the two red eges. When I get home tonight I'll try to figure out why this happens.

Answer (score 4):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction#Graph_algorithms_for_transitive_reduction) on transitive reduction points to an implementation within GraphViz (which is open source).  Not exactly pseudocode, but maybe someplace to start?

LEDA includes a [transitive reduction algorithm](http://www.algorithmic-solutions.info/leda_guide/graph_algorithms/transitive_closure.html).  I don't have a copy of the [LEDA book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521563291) anymore, and this function might have been added after the book was published.  But if it's in there, then there will be a good description of the algorithm.

Google points to [an algorithm](http://archives.free.net.ph/message/20090318.100030.d9d9ae84.it.html) that somebody suggested for inclusion in Boost.  I didn't try to read it, so maybe not correct?

Also, [this](http://www.mozart-oz.org/mogul/doc/smiele/graph/) might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks (belatedly!) for your response. In the end, I emailed the author of an algorithms book and asked him to verify whether some pseudocode I'd written was correct, which he kindly did.

Comment: The [tred source code](http://hg.research.att.com/graphviz/file/tip/cmd/tools/tred.c) is barely readable thanks to the absence of any comment in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Depth-first algorithm in pseudo-python:

```
for vertex0 in vertices:
    done = set()
    for child in vertex0.children:
        df(edges, vertex0, child, done)

df = function(edges, vertex0, child0, done)
    if child0 in done:
        return
    for child in child0.children:
        edge.discard((vertex0, child))
        df(edges, vertex0, child, done)
    done.add(child0)
```

The algorithm is sub-optimal, but deals with the multi-edge-span problem of the previous solutions. The results are very similar to what tred from graphviz produces.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm of "girlwithglasses" forgets that a redundant edge could span a chain of three edges.  To correct, compute Q = R x R+ where R+ is the transitive closure and then delete all edges from R that show up in Q.  See also the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Can you suggest some pseudocode for doing this?

The transitive reduction algorithm posted below would run on the transitive closure graph, so for an edge x-y which could also be reached by x-A-B-y, you would also have x-A-y and x-B-y.

Comment: What is Q supposed to represent? What do you do with it?

Answer (score 1):

ported  to java / jgrapht, the python sample on this page from @Michael Clerx:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.jgrapht.DirectedGraph;

public class TransitiveReduction<V, E> {

    final private List<V> vertices;
    final private int [][] pathMatrix;
    
    private final DirectedGraph<V, E> graph;
    
    public TransitiveReduction(DirectedGraph<V, E> graph) {
        super();
        this.graph = graph;
        this.vertices = new ArrayList<V>(graph.vertexSet());
        int n = vertices.size();
        int[][] original = new int[n][n];

        // initialize matrix with zeros
        // --> 0 is the default value for int arrays
        
        // initialize matrix with edges
        Set<E> edges = graph.edgeSet();
        for (E edge : edges) {
            V v1 = graph.getEdgeSource(edge);
            V v2 = graph.getEdgeTarget(edge);

            int v_1 = vertices.indexOf(v1);
            int v_2 = vertices.indexOf(v2);

            original[v_1][v_2] = 1;
        }
        
        this.pathMatrix = original;
        transformToPathMatrix(this.pathMatrix);
    }
    
    // (package visible for unit testing)
    static void transformToPathMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        // compute path matrix 
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) { 
                if (i == j) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (matrix[j][i] > 0 ){
                    for (int k = 0; k < matrix.length; k++) {
                        if (matrix[j][k] == 0) {
                            matrix[j][k] = matrix[i][k];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // (package visible for unit testing)
    static void transitiveReduction(int[][] pathMatrix) {
        // transitively reduce
        for (int j = 0; j < pathMatrix.length; j++) { 
            for (int i = 0; i < pathMatrix.length; i++) {
                if (pathMatrix[i][j] > 0){
                    for (int k = 0; k < pathMatrix.length; k++) {
                        if (pathMatrix[j][k] > 0) {
                            pathMatrix[i][k] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void reduce() {
        
        int n = pathMatrix.length;
        int[][] transitivelyReducedMatrix = new int[n][n];
        System.arraycopy(pathMatrix, 0, transitivelyReducedMatrix, 0, pathMatrix.length);
        transitiveReduction(transitivelyReducedMatrix);
        
        for (int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
                if (transitivelyReducedMatrix[i][j] == 0) {
                    // System.out.println("removing "+vertices.get(i)+" -> "+vertices.get(j));
                    graph.removeEdge(graph.getEdge(vertices.get(i), vertices.get(j)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

unit test :

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TransitiveReductionTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        int[][] matrix = new int[][] {
            {0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
        };
        
        int[][] expected_path_matrix = new int[][] {
            {0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
        };
        
        int[][] expected_transitively_reduced_matrix = new int[][] {
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
        };
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix) + " original matrix");

        int n = matrix.length;

        // calc path matrix
        int[][] path_matrix = new int[n][n];
        {
            System.arraycopy(matrix, 0, path_matrix, 0, matrix.length);
            
            TransitiveReduction.transformToPathMatrix(path_matrix);
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(path_matrix) + " path matrix");
            Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected_path_matrix, path_matrix);
        }

        // calc transitive reduction
        {
            int[][] transitively_reduced_matrix = new int[n][n];
            System.arraycopy(path_matrix, 0, transitively_reduced_matrix, 0, matrix.length);
            
            TransitiveReduction.transitiveReduction(transitively_reduced_matrix);
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(transitively_reduced_matrix) + " transitive reduction");
            Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected_transitively_reduced_matrix, transitively_reduced_matrix);
        }
    }
}
```

test ouput

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]] original matrix
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]] path matrix
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]] transitive reduction
```

Comment: For your information, a pull request with a reworked version of this code has been submitted, accepted and merged into jgrapht. https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/commit/474db1fdc197ac253f1e543c7b087cffd255118e

Comment: FYI, the algorithm in JGraphT does not work if the graph contains cycles, see [issue #667](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/issues/667). Could you maybe check what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python implementation that borrows from the [NetworkX](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/main/networkx/algorithms/dag.py#L808) library. Two functions used in it are topological sort to detect cycles, and DFS to find all vertices reachable from a staring vertex. All of these can be implemented without any dependencies, I’ve a complete implementation on my GitHub. However, it’s in a private repo, so, I’m copy-pasting the complete content of the module here.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from collections import defaultdict, deque
from typing import TypeVar, NamedTuple

T = TypeVar('T')


class Edge(NamedTuple):
    src: T
    dest: T


class Graph:
    def __init__(self, vertices: set[T] = None, edges: set[Edge] = None):
        self.vertices = vertices or set()
        self.edges = edges or set()
        self.adj = defaultdict(set)
        self.indegrees = defaultdict(int)
        for u, v in self.edges:
            self.vertices.add(u)
            self.vertices.add(v)
            self.adj[u].add(v)
            self.indegrees[v] += 1
        self.indegrees.update({v: 0 for v in (self.vertices - self.indegrees.keys())})

    def add_edge(self, edge: Edge) -> None:
        u, v, = edge
        self.vertices.add(u)
        self.vertices.add(v)
        self.edges.add(edge)
        self.adj[u].add(v)
        self.indegrees[v] += 1

    # Kahn's Algorithm
    def topological_sort(self) -> list[T]:
        indegrees = self.indegrees.copy()
        q = deque(node for node, degree in indegrees.items() if degree == 0)
        result = []
        while q:
            u = q.popleft()
            result.append(u)
            if u not in self.adj:
                continue
            for v in self.adj[u]:
                indegrees[v] -= 1
                if indegrees[v] == 0:
                    q.append(v)

        if len(result) != len(self.vertices):
            raise ValueError('Graph has a cycle')
        return result

    def dfs(self, start: T) -> list[Edge]:
        stack = [(None, start)]
        result = []
        visited = set()
        while stack:
            u, v = stack.pop()
            if u is not None:
                result.append(Edge(u, v))
            if v in visited or v not in self.adj:
                continue
            visited.add(v)
            for k in self.adj[v]:
                if k not in visited:
                    stack.append((v, k))
        return result

    # Input: DAG G=(V,E)
    #
    # E2 = E
    # for edge (u,v) in E2 do
    #     if there is a path from u to v in G=(V,E2) that does not use edge (u,v) then
    #         E2 = E2 - {(u,v)}   // remove edge (u,v) from E2
    #     end if
    # end for
    #
    # Output: G2=(V,E2) is the transitive reduction of G
    def transitive_reduction(self) -> Graph:
        # Throws exception if graph has a cycle.
        _ = self.topological_sort()

        tr = Graph(self.vertices)
        # descendants[v] is the list of all vertices reachable from v.
        descendants = {}
        indegrees = self.indegrees.copy()
        for u in self.vertices:
            if u not in self.adj:
                continue
            u_neighbors = self.adj[u].copy()
            for v in self.adj[u]:
                if v in u_neighbors:
                    if v not in descendants:
                        descendants[v] = {y for x, y in self.dfs(v)}
                    u_neighbors -= descendants[v]
                indegrees[v] -= 1
                if indegrees[v] == 0:
                    del indegrees[v]
            for v in u_neighbors:
                tr.add_edge(Edge(u, v))
        return tr
```

For a detailed discussion of improving the efficiency of the algorithm, see [this](https://github.com/jafingerhut/cljol/blob/master/doc/transitive-reduction-notes.md#computing-the-transitive-reduction-of-a-dag).