# Pseudocode for Transitive Reduction on Directed Cyclic Graph with Edge Weights

Tags: ruby, graph-theory, pseudocode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [transitive reduction algorithm: pseudocode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690953/transitive-reduction-algorithm-pseudocode)

I have a directed graph with edge weights and am looking for a way to get the [transitive reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) of it. Also this graph could have cycles so it needs to be able to handle that. I'm gunna eventually write this in ruby but any langauge will do!

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690953/transitive-reduction-algorithm-pseudocode

Comment: Rather than use *transitive reduction* and force everyone to have to read the Wikipedia article, it would be better to show your understanding of what you want, and use plain English.  Suggest: you're looking for a way to determine the *minimal representation* for a set of relations...