# Algorithm to find a hierarchy tree in a directed acyclic graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a graph with properties as shown below:

Adjacency Matrix:

[image]

Graph Representation:

[image]

Which algorithm can be applied to find a hierarchy tree of the above graph? In my words, a hierarchy tree is one in which nodes are connected and directed towards their immediate child only and any edge from current to child of child or any other should be removed.

For the above graph, a hierarchy tree would look like the following:

Hierarchy Tree:

[image]

Comment: Can you please reupload the images? It says that the first two aren't available.

Comment: Images should be uploaded to StackOverflow (well, technically imgur) in case external links go down. Click on "Add image" when [edit]ing the page and point it to a file stored on your computer or online.

Comment: Can you see them now ?

Comment: @Dukeling This time I hope you'll be able to

Comment: so edge 45 should also be removed. Or I missed something

Comment: No, the edge 6->5 should be removed

Comment: @luiso1979 As I read it, all edges to non-child ancestors should be removed.

Comment: @Dukeling what do you mean by "non-child ancestors"?

Comment: @luiso1979 [Ancestors](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4408/glossary.html#Ancestor) which aren't [children](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4408/glossary.html#Child). 5 isn't an ancestor of 4, thus 4-5 shouldn't be removed. 6-5 is the only edge from a node to its non-child ancestor (5 is 6's ancestor, but not its child).

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing ancestor and descendant. I meant "non-child descendants".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [Transitive Reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) is what you're looking for. Check this one : https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7096/transitive-reduction-of-dag

[Implementation Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690953/transitive-reduction-algorithm-pseudocode)